Finding x at maximum/peak of a Generalised Additive Model (GAM) of y~x
I am attempting to model species' responses to an environmental gradient to characterise their niche in terms of this gradient. I will be using a data on presence/absence of species in grids along this gradient, and a GAM so that I can have flexible shapes and incorporate a number of covariates.
The model will look something like this:
mgcv::gam(occurrence ~ s(gradient, k = 4) + covariates.... family = binomial).


Run for each species separately, with 4 knots to limit things to the anticipated unimodal (or monotonic) shape.
There are standard criteria for deriving parameters to describe species' niches modelled in this way derived by Heegaard (2002) that I want to use, these are:
Optimum - The value of the gradient where occurrence probability is maximised.
Central Borders - The values of the gradient where occurrence probability is exp(-0.5)*Optimum.
Outer Borders - The values of the gradient where occurrence probability is exp(-2)*Optimum.
Lots of people use these, and I've read quite a few papers that do so, but I'm struggling to work out how you'd actually calculate them in practice - it never seems to be described in the papers that I've read, and I can't find code with any of them. I guess this must just be one of those things that is so obvious most people don't state it, but I'd be grateful if someone could clear it up. This seems like a general question that a lot of people must have when using GAMs. Will most people just be predicting y over a very fine grid of x, and then extracting x for the y values that meet the criteria above?
I have also come across this  really helpful answer here, which also has suggestions on how to calculate confidence intervals for these parameters (something I'd also like to do). Seems like this could be the way to go?
Refs
Heegaard, E. (2002). The outer border and central border for species - Environmental relationships estimated by non-parametric generalised additive models. Ecological Modelling, 157(2–3), 131–139. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3800(02)00191-6

This is a really good question and really is about programming, not statistics. If nobody beats me to it, I'll have a go later this week. But the answer is to just modify the answer I supplied at [stats.se] to find the covariate value where the estimate of the expected value of the response is exp(-2)*Optimum say (or close to it), but you'll need to address the issues that you want to come at this from two directions; one from the left up to the optimum and no farther, and then from the right up to the optimum and no farther.
